# Show different banner after every 4 posts

Tags: php

I have created a while loop and there are 20 posts per page displaying so after every 5 post I would like to display different banner like this

post 1
post 2
post 3
post 4
post 5

banner 01

post 6
post 7
post 8
post 9
post 10

banner 02

I have tried using % operator with if condition but it is not working though below is my code any suggestion and help would be highly appreciated,

```
<?php 
            $post = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY bid DESC");
            $count_post = mysqli_num_rows($post); 
            while($have_posts = mysqli_fetch_assoc($post)) {
                $video = $have_posts['video'];
        ?>  
        <article>
            <h1 class="title"><a href="details.php?post=<?php echo $have_posts['bid']; ?>"><?php echo $have_posts['title']; ?></a></h1>

            <div class="content-img">
                <img src="admin/uploads/<?php echo $have_posts['ft_img']; ?>" alt="" />
            </div>  
        </article>  
        <?php 
            if($count_post%4 == 2) {
        ?>
            <img src="images/banner1" />
            <?php } ?>

        <?php 
            if($count_post%5 == 3) {
        ?>  
            <img src="images/banner2" />
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please notice what $count_post represent:

```
        $count_post = mysqli_num_rows($post);
```

Therefore, it's a **constant** number (total amount of posts) that doesn't reflect the current post's "number".

You need to use an additional variable, `$i = 0;` prior to the loop.
At the bottom (before closing the loop) - increase it by one `$i++;`.

Prior to the loop:

```
$i = 0;
$banner_number = 1;
```

Then simply change your condition:

```
if($i % 5 == 0){
 //show banner here
 echo '<img src="banners/banner-".$banner_number.".png">';
 $banner_number++;
 //First time: banners/banner-1.png
 //Second time: banners/banner-2.png ...
}
```

**Edit:**
In case your banners names are in the following format: `{constant_name}-{increasing_number}.png`, you can use an additional variable `$banner_number` and increase it by when only when you show a banner.